# Shopify fetch id of an image (media id) inside of .js.liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am trying to fetch ID of my product images inside of .js.liquid files. It is easy to do so from .liquid file directly but can't figure out how to do it from a .js file. In a .liquid file I simply put {{ media.id }} and it works, but trying different things in .js won't do the job. I tried to search for the issue but can't find anything...

I tried different types of code. Basically I have a string which generates a html for my product images on my homepage.

```
      thumbnailContainer.append('<img src="' + src +'" alt="qv-img" class="lazyload">');
```

- src + works fine, but when trying "media.id" or "id", it doesn't work properly. Can someone navigate me into the right direction?

Comment: You need to post another code also, this code not show what actually you tried till.